# Problems with storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard

recently I started using storyboard and I've the following situation: I want to set the text of an UILabel from the AppDelegate. So I created an instance of my ViewController

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                             bundle: nil];

    ViewController *controller = (ViewController*)[mainStoryboard 
                                                       instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"mainViewController"];

    myViewController = controller;

    [window addSubview:myViewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

and called the following method from the delegate

```
- (void) updateParameterLabel:(NSString *)parameter {

    NSLog(@"URL-2: %@", parameter);

    parameterLabel.text = parameter;
}
```

But the parameter is not shown in the UI.

Another think, which is kind of strage:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"View did Appear");
}
```

The "View did appear" is logged twice ...

Any hints?

Regards,
Sascha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to make it work, make the `UILabel` a property of your `viewcontroller` and set the label by using

In delegate :

```
- (void) updateParameterLabel:(NSString *)parameter {

    NSLog(@"URL-2: %@", parameter);
    [myViewController updateParemeter:parameter];
}
```

In myViewController:

```
- (void) updateParameterLabel:(NSString *)parameter {

    NSLog(@"URL-2: %@", parameter);

    parameterLabel.text = parameter;
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];//edit
}
```

So use the `viewController` to update your label. Of course you need the label as a `property` in your `viewController`

Comment: Well yes, that's how I actually implemented it, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the text of a `UILabel` from your application delegate isn't great design. Your view controllers should be managing the content of your views, hence their name. Typically your storyboard is instantiated automatically, and you don't need any of the `storyboardWithName` et code you've got, assuming you're working with Apple's default templates.

Maybe think about re-architecting your application to follow the 'model-view-controller' pattern more strictly, and also look at how Apple instantiate storyboards automatically (just create a new storyboard project in XCode to see this).

Comment: Hi,I think, my description was a bit unclear, of course I used a ViewController. The problem is that I overwrite - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url and I want to call the updateParameterLabel method from the viewcontroller to update the label.

Answer (score 0):

For what I see you are trying to update the label before it appears, so why don't you try calling your updateLabel method in the viewWillAppear, it would be something like this

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
 [self updateParameterLabel:@"Some Text"];
 [super viewWillAppear:YES];
}
```

And updateParameterLabel has to be implemented in the viewController.